# jQuery scroll image src change issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello!**

I'm having some terrible problems with jQuery. I want my script to change logo image if user scrolls page. Very simple yet it doesn't work. As soon as i scroll my page, pic dissapears and doesn't come back after i get back to the page top. Sorry for newbie question but i fought for 3 hours with it already. Stuff like http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-a-resizing-menu-bar/ doesn't help. I'm sure that my image sources are correct, because big logo loads upon page loading.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop()>1){
        $('#logo').attr('src', "Source\Pictures\Logo_small.jpg");
      }
    else {
        $('#logo').attr('src', "Source\Pictures\Logo.jpg");
      }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="Source\Pictures\Logo.jpg" id="logo">

<script src="Source\JavaScript\jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Source\JavaScript\index.js"></script>
```

Before scroll:
[image: This is what my menu bar looks like]

After scroll:
[image: This is what happens as soon as i scroll my page]

Comment: Use forward slashes instead of back slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using back slashes (`\`) in a string, you should double them (`\\`). This is because the back slash is an escape character, so the contents of the string are likely different than what you expect they are.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop()>1){
        $('#logo').attr('src', "Source\\Pictures\\Logo_small.jpg");
      } else {
        $('#logo').attr('src', "Source\\Pictures\\Logo.jpg");
      }
    });
});
```

Ideally though, you should use forward slashes, since back slashes will only work locally, on Windows. Forward slashes are also supported in Windows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop()>1){
        $('#logo').attr('src', "Source/Pictures/Logo_small.jpg");
      } else {
        $('#logo').attr('src', "Source/Pictures/Logo.jpg");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!